# AWS - EC2 - Instance running out of space

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am getting error that Instance running out of space. 
My current instance type is t2.micro and size of the instance was 10GB before and I have increased it with 5GB and now its 15GB but still my root directory gets full and same error comes again.
I have removed the logs file which consuming more space and there is no more backup files there also.

I have attached the disk full screenshot for same.

[image]

Thanks in advance.
Thanks

Comment: Why not deep dive in /dev/xvda1 and see which folder taking up the space? I don't think anyone here can help you except suggesting 1) increase the disk (or) 2) delete files which are consuming the space etc.,

Comment: Okay..let me try that . Thanks @INVOKECloud

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, open files which have reference issues tend to cause disk space issues.

Try the below command to find out the open files and check if they are present in the path, if not, you can kill the process

Command:

`sudo lsof | awk '{print $NF}'`